# Proving a differential equation of a cone

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to prove a differential equation of a partial cone (there is no tip):

> $$\dfrac{dh}{dt}=\frac{F_i-c\sqrt{h1}}{(\pi(r_1^2+(2r_1(r_2-r_1)*\frac{h_1}{h_2})+(\frac{r_2-r_1}{h2})^2*h_1^2)}$$
>   h1=height of liquid in tank, h2=height of tank, r1=radius at the bottom of the tank, r2 =radius at top, Fi= flow in, c is a constant

The denominator can be simplified because it is a perfect square to:

> $$((\frac{r_2-r_1}{h2})*h_1+r_1)^2$$

I am mainly trying to figure out how the denominator is achieved.  I recognize that its probably a change in volume wrt time. I just don't remember how to piece that together.

I was reading through other chapters in my book (that we haven't looked at yet and are several chapters ahead) and found an equation with respect to a cone similar to this problem that states.

> $$Area=pi*r^2$$, and that $$r=(\frac{(R)*h_1}{h_2})$$
>   Where R=the radius at the top of the tank.

How is that r obtained?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Math.SE. Please edit your question, so that your formulas are readable, using [the mathjax guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) if necessary. Also, I think that your notations might need to be described. What is the variable? What is a constant? Is it positive? ...

Comment: Well done with the formula! Now, what do you mean by "trying to prove a differential equation"? Do you want to a) solve it? b) show that it describes a situation? c) something different? Also, imagine reading this question for the first time. How would you know what $h$, $t$, $F_i$, $c$, $r_1$, $r_2$, $h_1$ and $h_2$ stand for without an explanation?